# Python - Deploying Voilà ways

Tags: python, heroku, widget, web-deployment, voila

I have created a python notebook with many widgets connected to many dataframes and I can deploy it fine with Voilà on my local host. I would like to understand what is in the simplest way possible I can share the link with people on my internal network and also outside.

I read my articles suggesting to use Heroku, Binder (with GitHub), Google App Engine, PythonAnywhere...

So my question is what do you suggest for my needs? I would like to keep the interface generated with Voilà and I was hooping not to share it public or at least not to everyone.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

There are services which allow you to 'essentially' put your localhost on the web i.e. they allow people to remotely access a website hosted as localhost on your machine. I have personally used https://ngrok.io. I've also heard of [localhost.run](https://localhost.run) which is a recently launched service. With these services, you will get a URL that you can now send to the folks who you would like to access your service. If you do this, your local machine (the one hosting the service) has to be on.

You can also go with the option of deploying to a host like Google App Engine (GAE), PythonAnywhere, Heroku, etc. But you should add some form of authentication so that access is only granted to those who provide that authentication.

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for a way to add some form of authentication before launching Voila on Heroku, however I cannot find any relevant docs, do you have something to suggest?